# Adding child views to Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Though I have been through many questions regarding relative layout and adding child view programatically, I am unable to resolve this issue

```
for (int i=0; i<views; i++) {

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    LayoutParams img_params= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    img_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    relativeLayout.addView(img, img_params);

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    LayoutParams text_params= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    relativeLayout.addView(textview, text_params);
}
```

I have added log below:

```
06-27 11:16:38.849: E/AndroidRuntime(20595): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: Your img and textView already added in any view. You should create new Image and TextView object for each new adding, or first remove your views from previous parent view

Comment: Dimmerg... i want all those views in my parent layout. and number of views are not known

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the same View objects in a loop over and over. The first time the loop runs the two Views are added and they now have a parent. They cant be added again.

You'll need to instantiate new instances of those views in every iteration for this to work.

Comment: @newBee you can't use `new ImageView()`. Views dont have default contructors. Pass the context to the constructor. Use `new ImageView(context)`. Do the same for the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Create new instances of `ImageView` and `TextView` inside the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < views; i++) {
    LayoutParams img_params= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    img_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    relativeLayout.addView(img, img_params);

    LayoutParams text_params= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    text_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    relativeLayout.addView(textview, text_params);
}
```